# Scala Queue implementation that is parallel/thread safe?

Tags: scala, thread-safety, queue

I have an implementation of a linked queue in scala, but it is not currently parallel-safe. I'm not sure what changes I need to make to make this implementation parallel-safe…any suggestions?

```
class LinkedQueue[A] extends Queue[A] {
  private class Node (var data:A, var next:Node)
  private var head:Node = null
  private var last:Node = null

  def isEmpty():Boolean = head == null

  def peek():A = {
    assert(head != null)
    head.data
  }

  def dequeue():A = {
    assert(head != null)
    val ret = head.data
    head = head.next
    if(head == null) last = head
    ret
  }

  def enqueue(elem:A) {
    if(last == null) {
      head = new Node(elem, null)
        last = head
    } else {
      last.next = new Node(elem, null)
      last = last.next
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this for educational purposes? Otherwise I would suggest you to use one of the existing classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package or a library like https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools.

Comment: This question is essentially code review; as such, it's off-topic on this site.

Comment: make it immutable.